# How can we make function globally in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a query to you all, I want to make  below function globally in codeigniter:

```
 $ci =& get_instance();
```

I have an fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context:
```

I want to use $ci for $this but how can I mention $ci =& get_instance() globally?

I have to put $ci =& get_instance(); code in every function and every file.
please help.

Here is my test code:

```
    public static function index()
    {   
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $redirect   = $ci->auth->is_logged_in(false, false);
    }
```

Comment: show us the code. this is not essential `$ci =& get_instance();`  always

Comment: Please check my code now @AbdullaNilam

Comment: Just  add `$this>auth->is_logged_in` is enaugh

Comment: Okay let me try @AbdullaNilam

Comment: add `$this` instead of `$ci`

Comment: solved @AbdullaNilam thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The issue is php version:

old version

```
$this->employees_model->get_all();
```

new version

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->employees_model->get_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper... In that you are able to create function with $ci =& get_instance(); & access it directly in controller,model,view etc.

```
example :

if (!function_exists('isLogin'))
{
    function isLogin(){
        //get main CodeIgniter object
        $ci =& get_instance();
        //your code
    }
} 

access directly isLogin() in controller like:
if(isLogin())
{
//Your code
}
```

Comment: I have done this. but how can I call in every file after create the helper function? @pAsh

Comment: You have to load the your custom helper in autoload.php like : $autoload['helper'] = array('your_helper'); the access it.

Comment: good and how can i call this in our controller files after load in autoload.php file?

Comment: directly function name : isLogin() (i already mention in above code) : ref :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037705/call-a-helper-function-in-controller-in-codeigniter